# Running Telegram Bot Python File forever

Tags: python, server, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am wondering if it is possible to run a telegram bot python file forever? Possibly without the use of a server. Is there anyway i can do this without having a spare PC to run the file?

Comment: you can run on your local computer and never turn it off.

Comment: I believe you can run it on Github using GitHub Actions.. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Right until you turn off your PC.